# Service callout to business service returns fault in OSB

Tags: oracle, osb, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-service-bus, oracle-soa

I have a proxy service which does service callout to business service to PUT data to a Rest endpoint.

When i tested the business service the PUT was successful and got 201 response.
When i tested the proxy service ,PUT failed with 400 bad request fault.I'm using same request payload and outbound for both cases

How come the same payload gives success response from business service and fault when tested via proxy service.

Is it possible that the proxy service alters the payload when passing it to business service internally? Please help.

Comment: Does the business service pass some additional headers which you might have missed adding in the service callout?
Log the payload in the request pipeline for service callout and see if the payload is correct

Comment: @boredDev I have logged the input payload for the service callout and compared it. It's exactly same as the request i'm using for testing business service.However i noticed one difference in the outbound variable,Proxy service adds the below tag automatically                                                                                           
 <con:doOutboundWss>true</con:doOutboundWss> but when testing business service there is no option to set this.

Comment: doOutboundWss is for passing security headers in the SOAP envelope. Does your business service have any WSS policy set on it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by disabling the "use chunked streaming mode" option in transport configurations page of business service.

Comment: Didn't worked for me.